# How to submit my changes in abc file which is old version while git has same abc file with new changes by other developer?

Tags: git, gerrit

To be more clear, I was working on file abc which was in my remote repository for a long time and some other developer worked on same file made new changes and merged. I checkout to my old commit after a long time which has old version of abc file and start make changes and push it.

When I compare my changes with base file (recent version of abc) some new changes are found and that new changes are required for our project. I do not want to replace their changes But how can I merge my changes with the latest version of abc file instead of replacing.

Comment: You will not overwrite their changes. Git will attempt to merge your changes during a `pull`/`merge`. If it is unable to do so automatically it will result in a "merge conflict" which you'll have to manually resolve between the two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to rebase your change.

You can try to use the Gerrit UI to perform the rebase:

1) Go to your change in the Gerrit UI
2) Click on "Rebase" button
3) Click on "Rebase" button again

If you have conflicts to be resolved you'll receive an error message and you'll need to perform the rebase manually in your local repository to resove de conflicts:

1) Update your local repository

```
git fetch
```

2) Rebase your commit (change the branch accordingly)

```
git rebase origin/master
```

3) If you find conflicts, resolve them

```
git mergetool
```

4) When you're done commit your changes

```
git rebase --continue
```

5) Push your new commit (patchset) to Gerrit

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```